# PHP and Twilio Real-time?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twilio, real-time

I'm currently working on a real-time SMS System but I'm fairly positive that my current implementation is a terrible practice and I'm looking for guidance to be more efficient with this.

## The Attempt

Currently, when you load up the interface it pulls all the text messages for that number you have selected. Then it fires off an ajax call every 5 seconds to the Twilio JSON PHP script I've written asking for messages newer than the last message in the list.

```
$.getJSON("/includes/twilio.php",{action:"getconvo",cid:customer.customer_number},function(data){
        $('#sms_messages').html("<div></div>");
        $(data.messages).each(function(){
            insertSMS(this.msg,this.date,this.from);
            lastMessage = this.date;
        });
        $("#sms_messages").animate({ scrollTop: $('#sms_messages > div').height()},"fast");
        shouldUpdate = true;
        sms_interval = setInterval(function(){updateSMS(customer.customer_number)},5000);
});
```

Update Function

```
function updateSMS(cid){
    if(shouldUpdate){
        $.getJSON("/includes/twilio.php",{action:"getconvo",cid:cid,date:lastMessage},function(data){
            if(data.messages.length > 0){
                // Play an embeded sound effect when a new message is found.
                $('#sms_sound')[0].play();
                $(data.messages).each(function(){
                    insertSMS(this.msg,this.date,this.from);
                    lastMessage = this.date;
                });
                $("#sms_messages").animate({ scrollTop: $('#sms_messages > div').height()},"fast");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Code review requests are off-topic here. There is appropriate [SE site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for such questions.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I don't recommend polling the Twilio API to get "real time" SMS messages. Polling is inefficient and will keep both your servers as well as Twilio's servers busy for longer than is necessary.

Rather, I would use Twilio's [webhooks to receive messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request). Then, while you are on the page to receive messages I would implement either Server Sent Events ([see this article for an in depth description of SSE as well as example PHP code to implement](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)) or web sockets (here's an article on [web sockets in PHP](http://srchea.com/build-a-real-time-application-using-html5-websockets) and the [library built as part of it](https://github.com/srchea/PHP-Push-WebSocket/)) in order to push new messages that you receive from the webhook to your page.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to dig into the article and see what I can come up with. :)

Comment: Awesome, hope it goes well!